# Nuget sources update fails to update

Tags: nuget

Following the [nuget command line reference](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/Command-Line-Reference#sources-command), I update an internal nuget source URL to a new URL.  The update fails.

#### Execute

`nuget sources`

#### Output

1. nuget.org [Enabled]
   http://www.nuget.org/api/v2
2. InternalFeed [Enabled]
   http://oldserver:8888/nuget

#### Execute

- `nuget sources Update -Name InternalFeed -Source http://newserver:8888/nuget`

> Package source "InternalFeed" was successfully updated.

- `nuget sources`

#### Output

1. nuget.org [Enabled]
   http://www.nuget.org/api/v2
2. InternalFeed [Enabled]
   http://oldserver:8888/nuget

#### Expected output

1. nuget.org [Enabled]
   http://www.nuget.org/api/v2
2. InternalFeed [Enabled]
   http://newserver:8888/nuget

Actual output does not match expected output.  How can I update the InternalFeed URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a file in the root directory called **NuGet.Config**.  This file contained the oldserver value.  I removed the value from **NuGet.Config**.  The update took after making said change.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution instead of hunting down a nuget.config is to `remove` the old source and `add` it again with the new url.